# How to fetch Tags from infusionsoft application?

Tags: php, api, infusionsoft

I would like to fetch all the tags using PHP API which I created in the Infusionsoft.

I have tried lot there is no sample codes available on the net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While trying to use the above answer, I found that one parameter is not matching with the current documentation. So according to the current document, I have updated the code -

```
$table = 'ContactGroup';
$limit = 1000;
$page = 0;
$queryData = array('Id' => '%');
$selectedFields = array('Id','GroupName');
$orderBy = 'Id';
$ascending = true;

$tags = $infusionsoft->data()->query($table, $limit, $page, $queryData, $selectedFields, $orderBy, $ascending); 

print "<pre>";
print_r($test);
```

It is done using the php. Other methods (php-isdk etc..) should work the same. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Thank you.. The above answer was posted two years back

Answer (score 2):

Here is the PHP code for returning all Contact Tags from the ContactGroup table...

```
<?php
    $fields = array('Id','GroupName');
    $query = array('Id' => '%');
    $result = $app->dsQuery('ContactGroup', 1000, 0, $query, $fields);
    $count=count($result); 

    for( $x = 0; $x < $count; $x++ ) {                
        echo $result[$x]['Id'] . "<br>";
        echo $result[$x]['GroupName'] . "<br>";
    }    
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an [SDK](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/xml-rpc/) provided by Infusionsoft that will assist with common API requests.

You will want to use the [DataService.query](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/xml-rpc/#data-find-a-record-by-matching-a-specific-field) method to query the "ContactGroup" (the original name of a "tag") table ([table/field list](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/table-schema/)).

Answer (score 0):

I've created a Service Class that I use in all the projects that has Infusionsoft Integration.

Here's how I have it.

```
public function getTags() {
    $tags = [];
    $page = 0;

    do {
        $result = $this->infusionsoft
            ->data
            ->query('ContactGroup', 1000, $page, ['id' => '%'], ['id', 'GroupName', 'GroupCategoryId'], 'GroupName', true);

        $tags = array_merge($tags, $result);

    } while (count($result) === 1000);

    return $tags;

}
```